# Different login views for different flask blueprints

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I have a flask web application and it has multiple blueprints:

- restserver
- webserver

Most of the endpoints in both webserver and restserver require the user to be logged-in. I use flask-login extension, which provides `@login_required` decorator.

Is it possible to have different `login_view` for different blueprints?

```
# for web blueprint
login_mananger.login_view = '/web/login'

 .. so on
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the most important specialities of RESTful is statelessness, it means the server won't "remember" any information from clients, the requests from clients should have contained all the needed informations, including auth informations.

Back to your question, you don't have to use Flask-Login for RESTful service authentication, and you should not use cookies or sessions because of the diversity of the clients. You can DIY the HTTP authentication of course, but [Flask-HTTPAuth](https://flask-httpauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is what you really need.

Here is a simplest example of Flask-HTTPAuth:

```
from flask.ext.httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth 
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

@auth.verify_password
def verify_password(username, password):
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first() 
    if not user: 
        return False
    g.current_user = user
    # You should accomplish the verify_password function by yourself in the User model.
    return user.verify_password(password)
```

According to the doc of Flask-HTTPAuth:

> The callback function takes two arguments, the username and the
>   password and must return True or False.

**You should notice that the initialization of the Flask-HTTPAuth just in the blueprint rather than the whole application since this authentication just used in your restserver blueprint.**

Then there is a function just like Flask-login's @login_required which provided by Flask-HTTPAuth:

```
@app.route('/private')
@auth.login_required
def private_page():
    return "Only for authorized people!"
```

This "login_required" callback function will be called when authentication is succesful. Since all of your restserver's route should be protected, you can use a "before_request" handler for applying the protection to the whole blueprint. Assuming that your restserver blueprint's name is "rest" and you have saved the user object in "g" just like what we do before:

```
from flask import jsonify

@rest.before_request 
@auth.login_required 
def before_request(): 
    if not g.current_user:
        return jsonify({'error':'Unauthorized.'})
```

I think this will do the trick. What I wrote above is just the simplest example and you can do much better in many ways, such as replacing the user credentials with token after first request. I believe that you will figure it out.

If my answer is helpful, it will be my great honour if you can "upvote" for this answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need to place the login manager declaration in the same file as the flask app instance. This is commonly an `__init__.py` file with the `app = Flask(__name__).` 
At the top, import LoginManager class

```
from flask_login import LoginManager
```

Then tie it to the app instance.

```
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
```

(This was not asked but just incase someone needs it) Lets say you have admins and normal users and you are authenticating from different tables:

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    x = Users.query.get(str(user_id))
    if x == None:
        x = Admins.query.get(str(user_id))
    return x
```

Finally after importing blueprints you can define the login views for each in a dictionary

```
login_manager.blueprint_login_views = {
    'admin': '/admin/login',
    'site': '/login',
}
```